# How do I move empty space on hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I have a 500GB hard drive, internal, and it is split as follows:

```
   Partition  Type Mount Point     Size      Used     Flags       
1. /dev/sda1 ntfs /media/BackupHD 433.55GiB  408.76    boot
2. /dev/sda3 ext4                  11.24GiB  336.89MiB  
3. /dev/sda2 extended              18.96GiB   18.96GiB
   /dev/sda5 ext4  /               12.96GiB   11.48GiB
   /dev/sda6 linuxswap              6.00GiB    --
```

So, originally when I set up Ubuntu I gave it 20Gb, or as it states above, 18.96Gb. It split that into 13Gb for the OS and 6Gb for swap. Fine. 
Now I need more space for Linux, as I like it more than Windows at the moment. I need to give the 11.24Gb from sda3 over to sda5 to increase it to about 24Gb. I try to do it within Ubuntu and it won't let me because I can't umount the partition that is running Linux, makes sense. 
I am having issues rebooting into an environment where I can move this space around. Gparted on a live cd would work, but I burned Ubuntu 14.04 x64 onto a DVD using Brasero, rebooted and it won't boot to the disc. I checked boot order and it is set to boot to cd before hard drive. 
Any ideas on how to move this space around either in or out of Ubuntu?

Comment: You should be able to boot from the Live DVD; either access the BIOS boot menu using the appropriate key and boot from the DVD-ROM or enter the BIOS and swap the boot order of the drives setting the DVD-ROM as first. Your motherboard's manual should provide the correct keys to use to do both things. If you're still unable to boot from the Live DVD, you can try to create a bootable USB by removing all the partitions on it and writing the Live DVD image to it; for example, if the USB drive is `/dev/sdb`, `dd if=ubuntu-image.iso of=/dev/sdb`

Comment: Also in case you did the above in order to boot from the Live DVD correctly already, make sure that the `md5` sum of the Live DVD matches the `md5` sum of the image you burned by running `md5sum /dev/sr0`

Comment: You will have to get your computer to boot from some kind of live cd/usb.